# Converting CSV file to xml file using apache camel : XML File is not being created

Tags: xml, apache, csv, apache-camel

```
public class ConverterRoute implements RoutesBuilder {

    public void addRoutesToCamelContext(CamelContext context) throws Exception {
        Tracer tracer = new Tracer();
        tracer.setTraceOutExchanges(true);

        // we configure the default trace formatter where we can
        // specify which fields we want in the output
        DefaultTraceFormatter formatter = new DefaultTraceFormatter();
        formatter.setShowOutBody(true);
        formatter.setShowOutBodyType(true);

        // set to use our formatter
        tracer.setFormatter(formatter);

        context.addInterceptStrategy(tracer);
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            public void configure() {


                try {
                    DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(com.dto.EmployeeDTO.class);
                          from("file://TEST?fileName=Employee.csv").
                          unmarshal(bindy).
                          marshal().
                          xstream().
                          to("file://TESTOUT?fileName=EmployeeXML.xml");
                    /*DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(com.dto.EmployeeDTO.class);
                      from("F://Employee.csv").
                      unmarshal(bindy).
                      marshal().
                      xstream().
                      to("F://EmployeeXML.xml");*/
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            ConverterRoute route = new ConverterRoute();
            System.out.println("Starting........");
            route.addRoutesToCamelContext(context);
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Ending........");
            context.stop();
        }catch(Exception exe){
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@CsvRecord(separator = ",", skipFirstLine = true)
public class EmployeeDTO implements Serializable{
@XmlAttribute
      @DataField(pos = 1)
      private int employeeId;
      @XmlAttribute
      @DataField(pos = 2)
      private String firstName;
      @XmlAttribute
      @DataField(pos = 3)
      private String lastName;
      @XmlAttribute
      @DataField(pos = 4)
      private String role;
}
```

I'm getting following error:

> Starting........
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   Ending........

Converted xml is not being generated in desire folder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the WARNING says that there is no log4j configuration file present on the classpath. Try adding a file named "log4j.properties" with the following content in your resources directory:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out
# uncomment the following line to turn on Camel debugging
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel.component.mongodb=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=[%30.30t] %-30.30c{1} %-5p %m%n
```

By doing above, you will get the logs in your IDE and can see what's going on.

Lastly, you could use JAXB instead of XTREAM. The only thing you need to do, is to annotate EmployeeDTO with JAXB annotations.